# How can I replace continue and goto statements with structured equivalent?

Tags: c++, loops

I wrote code but my professor said that using `continue` and `goto` is bad practice. I've tried replacing the `continue` statement with another while loop, but it is giving me the incorrect output. What is the structure to a continue and goto statement?

```
void getrare(int *arr, int *ordered, int len)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < len; ++index)
    {
        int n = arr[index];
        int d = 0;
        while (n)
        {
            d = n % 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            {
                if (i == index) 
                    continue;
                if (num_contains(d, arr[i]))
                    goto next_num;
            }
            ++ordered[index];
        next_num:
            n /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it your program is trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`goto` is considered bad practice. I don't why he said it on `continue` as well.

Anyhow - changing the continue is easy - simply reverse the if

```
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if (i != index) 
            {
                if (num_contains(d, arr[i]))
                    goto next_num;
            }
        }
```

Or even more simplfied:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if (i != index && num_contains(d, arr[i])) 
                    goto next_num;
        }
```

Now, to get rid of the goto.
In this specific case you use the `goto` for breaking the loop and skipping the ++. so you can just change it to:

```
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if (i != index && num_contains(d, arr[i])) 
               break;
        }
        if (i == len)
             ++ordered[index];
        ...
```

Note: I performed this changes on your code as is. Without reviewing what it does or what it suppose to do. This are just general code optimization methods.

**Edit**

To avoid using the `break` as well - you can use the condition in the `if` to stop it.
Personally, I prefer the `break`. It is much more clear and this is what it exists in the language.

```
        int i, stop = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < len && !stop; ++i)
        {
            if (i != index && num_contains(d, arr[i])) 
               stop = 1;
        }
        if (i == len) //Or you can use if(!stop)
           ++ordered[index];
```

Comment: Note that you can hoist `n /= 10;` to above the for loop (since the value of `n` isn't used there)

Comment: "I don't why he said it on continue as well." -- There are people saying `continue` and `break` are bad style because they interrupt the flow and make code less readable (as the loop conditions are not fully contained in the head). Although it may be true in some cases, I consider it exaggerated as a general statement. Forcefully abandoning those keywords often leads to *even worse* code with complex loop conditions.

Comment: This works and still gives the proper output, but he says the same about `break` statements. Would I just terminate the loop condition in order to break out the loop? Thanks again for the help...

Comment: I agree with @TheOperator that avoid using  `continue` and `break` is too much. But if this is the exercise, you can use the 'for' confition to stop it. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which requires only a minimal change to your code:

```
void getrare(int *arr, int *ordered, int len)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < len; ++index)
    {
        int n = arr[index];
        int d = 0;
        while (n)
        {
            d = n % 10;
            int i;      // keep track of loop counter outside the loop
            for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            {
                if (i != index && num_contains(d, arr[i]))
                    break;
            }
            // only increment the array if the loop exited before
            // completing (implying the goto would have happened)
            if (i == len)
            {
                ++ordered[index];
            }
            // but always execute this next line of code
            n /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`continue` is bad in this particular case and `goto` is bad in general. I have just shown you the relevant part below:

```
while (n)
{
    d = n % 10;
    for (int i = 0; 
         i < len && !num_contains(d, arr[i]); 
         ++i);
    if(i == len)
      ++ordered[index];
    n /= 10;
}
```

I don't know what exactly you are doing, but I haven't changed your core logic either.

Comment: You have changed the core logic - your code always does `++ordered[index];` but the original code only did it if `num_contains` always returned false;

Comment: This is what I meant with [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117901/how-can-i-replace-continue-and-goto-statements-with-structured-equivalent/33117967?noredirect=1#comment54049820_33117967) above. I find this loop condition more difficult to decipher than if it were contained in the body.

Comment: They are not independent of each other - if the `goto` is followed then the `++ordered[index] will not be performed.

Comment: @TheDark, I stand corrected. Now I have edited it. It seems that there is no importance of `i == index` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting in sub function help to get rid of break; continue goto in loop:

```
bool does_contain(const int* arr, int len, int d, int ignoredIndex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i != ignoredIndex && num_contains(d, arr[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void getrare(const int *arr, int *ordered, int len)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < len; ++index)
    {
        int n = arr[index];

        while (n)
        {
            int d = n % 10;
            if (!does_contain(arr, len, d, index)) {
                ++ordered[index];
            }
            n /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```